# How to create a top-level window in WPF that looks like a "UWP" app?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, windows-10

I need to create a WPF custom window which looks similar to:
[this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz4xR.png)

is there any way i could do that ?

I tried using  MahApps.Metro Window but the window was very much flickering while resizing.
here is the sample code:

```
 <Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahAppsMetroSample.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
                      Title="MahApps.Metro.Sample"
                      GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

  <Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
      <Button Content="settings" />
      <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <iconPacks:PackIconModern Width="24" Height="24" Kind="FoodCupcake" />
            <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="deploy cupcakes" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
  </Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>

  <Grid>
  </Grid>

</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: i have used mahapps.metro before but the window was very much flickering when i resize the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can implement it using a package know as UWP Host.
[UWP Host - Github](https://github.com/Selastin-George/UWP-Host)

[UWP Host - Nuget](https://nuget.org/packages/UWPHost)

**STEP 1:**
 All you need to do is import UWP Host into your project through nuget.

**STEP 2:**

Add this code to your App.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UWPHost;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
```

**STEP 3:**

Add this namespace to the window that you want to change

```
xmlns:uwp="clr-namespace:UWPHost;assembly=UWPHost"
```

**STEP 4:**


Add uwp prefix to the window tag and make sure that it look similar to this

```
<upw:Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:uwp="clr-namespace:UWPHost;assembly=UWPHost"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ShowTitlebar="true" Theme="Light"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

</uwp:Window>
```

**Step 5**

Inherit the UWPHost.Window class

eg:

```
public partial class MainWindow : UWPHost.Window{
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

**And That's it**

Comment: Thank you it worked